# Howto split a string into character groups in actionscript?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, actionscript, split

I need a string splitted into groups of characters in ActionScript like this:

```
var txt:String = "Hello World";
var arr:Array = txt.split(3);
// Now arr should contain a value like: ["Hel", "lo ", "Wor", "ld"]
```

This is possible in PHP like this:

```
$arr = str_split(txt, 3);
```

But I need a ActionScript equivalent of this PHP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
var txt:String = "Hello World";
var arr:Array = txt.match(/.{3}|.+/g);
trace(arr);
// Hel,lo ,Wor,ld
```